# Как понять логику?

Tags: php

Читал статью «почему не любят php». И там был пример, приводился этот код:

```
<?php
$arg = 'T';
$vehicle = (  $arg == 'B'  ? 'bus' :
     $arg == 'A'  ? 'airplane' :
     $arg == 'T'  ? 'train' :
     $arg == 'C'  ? 'car' :
     $arg == 'H'  ? 'horse' :
    'feet' );
    echo $vehicle;
```

У меня вопрос, Почему результат будет `horse`, а не `train`? Что это за логика языка? Я уже две книги заказал по php, а тут такие логические проблемы, да и ещё их не исправляют.

Comment: А зачем использовать для этого тернарные операторы? Чем обычная вид `if / else` не подошел? И для этого можно использовать `switch()`.

Comment: "да и ещё их не исправляют." - исправили уже. в седьмой версии. Правда не помню в какой точно. Кажется 7.4. Ну а в целом - зачем такая монстроузная конструкция? Она просто нечитабельная и за такое руки надо отрывать сразу

Comment: @СергейМишин, все верно, в 7.4. [Подробнее тут.](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-7-4-support-deprecated-unparenthesized/)

Answer (score 5):

Не знаю для чего используется такая ужасная конструкция, даже на привычном `if/else`, все выглядит более читабельнее и не режет глаза:

```
$arg = 'T';

if ($arg == 'B') $d = 'bus';
elseif ($arg == 'A') $d = 'airplane';
elseif ($arg == 'T') $d = 'train';
elseif ($arg == 'C') $d = 'car';
elseif ($arg == 'H') $d = 'horse';
else $d = 'feet';

echo $d; // train
```

Хотя в идеале сюда подошел бы `switch`:

```
$arg = 'T';

switch ($arg) {
    case 'B': $d = 'bus'; break;
    case 'A': $d = 'airplane'; break;
    case 'T': $d = 'train'; break;
    case 'C': $d = 'car'; break;
    case 'H': $d = 'horse'; break;
    default: $d = 'feet';
}

echo $d; // train
```

Если исправить ваш код, путем добавления правильных скобок (работает в php 7.4), то:

```
$arg = 'T';

$d = (
    $arg == 'B'
    ? 'bus'
    : ($arg == 'A'
        ? 'airplane'
        : ($arg == 'T' 
            ? 'train' 
            : ($arg == 'C' 
                ? 'car'
                : ($arg == 'H'
                    ? 'horse'
                    : 'feet'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

echo $d; // train
```

Как уже сказал [@СергейМишин](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199253/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD), спасибо ему за комментарий, более логичной и простой для этого подойдет использование ассоциативного массива:

```
$cfg = [
    'A' => 'airplane',
    'B' => 'bus',
    'T' => 'train',
    'C' => 'car',
    'H' => 'horse',
    'default' => 'feet'
];

$arg = 'T';
echo $cfg[$arg] ?? $cfg['default'];
```

Comment: "Хотя в идеале сюда подошел бы switch:" - в идеале тут подошёл бы ассоциативный массив, или Map))

Comment: @СергейМишин, да, согласен. Более логинее.

Comment: `switch` в отличие от ассоциативного массива позволяет описать все значения, включая дефолтное в едином блоке кода. а в приведенном массиве у вас посреди кода откуда не возьми приплетается еще `feet`. Сделайте тогда уж `$cfg = [.... 'default' => 'feet'];` и `$cfg[$arg] ?? $cfg['default']`

Answer (score 5):

Всё довольно просто: в php свой, довольно специфический, порядок выполнения тернарного оператора: конструкция

```
true ? 1 : true ? 2 : 3
```

в большинстве языков (скажем, в JS, Java, C++, Python, Ruby, Perl) будет выполняться в том же порядке, что и

```
true ? 1 : (true ? 2 : 3)
```

в php же порядок выполнения будет соответствовать

```
(true ? 1 : true) ? 2 : 3
```

Это непривычно и не слишком удобно; [мануал](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) не описывает какой-то специальной логики, разве что можно понимать это как "побольше ассоциативности слева направо" (как с арифметическими операторами: `1 / 2 / 3` – то же, что `(1 / 2) / 3`). Мануал упоминает, что лучше на порядок выполнения вообще не полагаться, и что он может быть изменён со сменой версии языка:

> PHP does not (in the general case) specify in which order an expression is evaluated and code that assumes a specific order of evaluation should be avoided, because the behavior can change between versions of PHP or depending on the surrounding code.

но из соображений обратной совместимости представляется маловероятным, что это изменят. См также [deprecation в 7.4](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-7-4-support-deprecated-unparenthesized/)